# Can I deduct remaining LLC losses against W2 wages once the LLC is dissolved?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, income

I have been a minority owner of an Ohio LLC. The franchise closed in 2009 but the LLC just dissolved December of 2014.

I haven't been able to deduct losses from my W2 wages as I haven't been actively doing anything with the LLC and am a minority owner.

I had been told that once the LLC dissolved I would be able to claim the losses against active income/W2 wages. In researching this I can't seem to confirm that this is allowable.

Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about [passive loss carryover](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p925/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000296629). Yes, you can deduct them once the entity which generated them is dissolved. If your K-1 is marked final (one of the two check-boxes on the top of the form) - you can apply the losses to any income. See the [IRS Publication 925](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p925/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000104640) for details.